# How to enable syntax highlighting for Mustache .mu files in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, mustache

I have latest version of PhpStorm with **Handlebars/Mustache** plugin enabled.
It works great with `.mustache` files but not with `.mu` files.

How can I explain to IDE that they are basically the same and it should highlight them to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manualy add new file type from the Settings (**File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types** ) like on the screen below:

[image]